# how can run automatic Regenerate Product lookup tables on WooCommerce -> Status -> Tools by cron jobs?

Tags: woocommerce

I have imported the products using some API's. But Every time I import the products, it's ask to regenerate the woocommerce lookup tables. So how can I run Regenerate Product lookup tables on `WooCommerce -> Status -> Tools` by cron jobs programmatically?

Comment: Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service and that we expect you to provide your code attempt in your question with all necessary details.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is over a year old so I'm guessing you've either figured it out or moved on. I'm posting this here more as a shortcut for anyone looking into this in the future.

**You have a few ways you can accomplish regenerating product lookup tables for WooCommerce.**

### 1. Use the WooCommerce REST API

The WooCommerce REST API documentation is pretty helpful here. Do a GET request to get a list of all the available tools from system status, then run a PUT request as noted in the docs here - https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-a-tool-from-system-status

You'll want to generate API keys in WooCommerce before making those requests. They've got it pretty well documented here as well - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

### 2. Use the WP-CLI

If you're a die-hard WordPress developer you could benefit from using the WP-CLI tool - https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/

You'd run the command `wp wc tool run regenerate_product_lookup_tables --user=1`

### 3. Bake it into the WordPress admin panel

As noted in the WooCommerce developer documentation you can use the `update_lookup_table` method from the `WC_Data_Store_WP` class - https://developer.woocommerce.com/2019/04/01/performance-improvements-in-3-6/

This feels overkill since you can just go to `WooCommerce > Status > Tools > Product lookup tables` and click the "Regenerate" button on the right. I guess it could be useful if you're using an automation tool like Selenium to log into your WordPress and do things. I could see the benefit of using `update_lookup_table` in a custom admin page or plugin to reduce the amount of clicks and page loads that your script would need to navigate.